# Retaining Firebase auth credentials after redirect

Tags: reactjs, firebase, web, oauth, firebase-authentication

I'm using Firebase authentication (`react-firebaseui` with Google & Facebook sign-in) in a single page web app in which the user also needs to authenticate against other systems using OAuth redirect flow to gain access to 3rd party APIs.

My problem is that Firebase authentication credentials are lost after the user authenticates to these 3rd party systems through OAuth (redirect flow).

How can I retain the Firebase authentication session and regain Firebase credentials after the redirect?

I've tried persisting the authentication credentials and then invoking `signInAndRetrieveDataWithCredential` after the redirect, but this doesn't appear to work.

Comment: Make a cookie or save it in local storage

Comment: If I store `AuthCredential` object and try to use it with `signInAndRetrieveDataWithCredential` I get the following error:
`signInAndRetrieveDataWithCredential` failed: First argument "credential" must be a valid credential.

Comment: Please add some code what you are doing for saving auth credential and using it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method is always called whether you sign in or sign out of firebase.

```
`firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
     if (user) {
           // User is signed in.
      }
  });`
```

You can use this method to get your user

Comment: I did actually have the `onAuthStateChanged` callback, but your answer got me thinking and I found the bug was actually in how I was using React (I was setting up the `onAuthStateChanged` in the wrong component). So, thanks!